# ruby apply method to string interpolation

Tags: ruby, string, interpolation, absolute

I want to convert a neg number to a pos in ruby so am using the abs method.

```
puts("You are #{playerGuess - num} away")
```

this is the current code but want to make the result from playerGuess - num always positive. how does one apply the abs method to this? if I do `#{playerGuess - num}` it just outputs the word `abs`

Comment: If `playerGuess` and `num` are both `Fixnum`'s, the doc for `abs` is here: [Numeric#abs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-abs). If one or both are `Float`'s (so their difference is a `Float`), it is here: [Float#abs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-abs). [Numeric#abs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-abs) covers both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
puts("You are #{(playerGuess - num).abs} away")
```